How to use GitHub immutable values (IDs) in Attribute Conditions?
Configuring auth to Google Cloud from GitHub Actions includes security considerations that make the seemingly sensible recommendation to bind using GitHub's immutable|unique IDs (owner|repo) rather than names.
Even though Google recommends IDs, its documentation refers to names:
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools providers create-oidc "my-repo" \
--project="${PROJECT_ID}" \
--location="global" \
--workload-identity-pool="github" \
--display-name="My GitHub repo Provider" \
--attribute-mapping="google.subject=assertion.sub,attribute.actor=assertion.actor,attribute.repository=assertion.repository,attribute.repository_owner=assertion.repository_owner" \
--attribute-condition="assertion.repository_owner == '${OWNER}'" \
--issuer-uri="https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com"

I understand how to revise the --attribute-condition to use the IDs but, how do I change the --attribute-mapping to incorporate them?
Naively revising --attribute-mapping values to e.g. attribute.repository_id=assertion.repository_id to match --attribute-condition values assertion.repository_owner_id=="{OWNER_ID}" doesn't work.
I know that the ID claims are included thanks to the GitHub OIDC Debugger:
{
  ...
  "repository": "{OWNER}/{REPO}",
  "repository_id": "{REPO_ID}",
  "repository_owner": "{OWNER}",
  "repository_owner_id": "{OWNER_ID}",
  ...
}


Looks like you need GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER and GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID env vars for assertion.repository_owner and assertion.repository_owner_id. See the default envrironment variables for the complete list.

The solution appears to be:

Leaving the --attribute-mapping either unchanged (must contain repository and repository_owner) or adding (repository_id and repository_owner_id)
Using the IDs in --attribute-condition (per the security considerations) and optionally/redundantly (!?) including/retaining the name predicates.

Minimally:
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools providers create-oidc "my-repo" \
--project="${PROJECT_ID}" \
--location="global" \
--workload-identity-pool="github" \
--display-name="My GitHub repo Provider" \
--attribute-mapping="google.subject=assertion.sub,attribute.actor=assertion.actor,attribute.repository=assertion.repository,attribute.repository_owner=assertion.repository_owner" \
--attribute-condition="assertion.repository_owner_id == '${OWNER_ID}' && assertion.repository_id == '${REPO_ID}'" \
--issuer-uri="https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com"


In addition to Azeem’s comment, you also need to make sure that single quotes are preserved. I believe you had them in the original code block.

Thanks for the suggestion. The CEL appears to accept double- (") or single-quotes (') without issue.
